# Why SQLYog changes delimiter when it creates MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, delimiter, sqlyog

When I make a stored procedure with SQLYog, it gives me this template:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `apachelogs`.`test`()
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I wonder why it changes delimiter before creating stored procedure. And why I can still use `;` delimiter inside of `create` statement(I guess it may because of scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That changes the statement delimiter to `$$` to keep MySQL from trying to interpret any semicolons inside the stored procedure as a delimiter. Without the `DELIMITER $$`, you wouldn't be able to define a stored procedure that contained `;` to delimit statements inside it. You can think of it as a way to globally escape the semicolon for the duration of the procedure's definition.

From the [fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

> To redefine the *mysql* delimiter, use the `delimiter` command. The following example shows how to do this for the `dorepeat()` procedure just shown. The delimiter is changed to `//` to enable the entire definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then restored to `;` before invoking the procedure. This enables the `;` delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by *mysql* itself.

I don't know if my explanation is any clearer than the manual's but maybe one of them (or both combined) will result in some understanding.